# Обернуть подстроки в HTML теги, Python

Tags: html, python, строки

Как я могу обернуть подстроки в строке в Python, в необходимые HTML теги, к примеру, есть строка:

````
<P>
Tite Post
```
include you code here
```
</p>
````

В которой, необходимо заменить строку между двумя группами символов ``` на теги `<code>` и `</code>` соответственно.

Comment: 1. найти генератор markdown to html 2. считать пары ``` и заменять их на теги <code> и </code>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как на счет примитивной регулярки?

````
import re

In [7]: print(s)

<P>
Tite Post
```
include you code here
```
</p>


In [8]: print(re.sub(r'```(.*?)```', r'<code>\1</code>', s, flags=re.S|re.M))

<P>
Tite Post
<code>
include you code here
</code>
</p>
````

PS вложенные случаи правильно обрабатываться не будут, но в вашем случае это невозможно т.к. нет возможности отличить начало блока от конца